# site performance of SharePoint 2013 vs 2010

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, page-load

I have read in few blogs that site performance of 2013 is better and pages load faster that they do in 2010.

What are the items that have been improved on this front? (like Minimal Download Strategy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things

1. [Distributed Cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20348.sharepoint-2013-appfabric-and-distributed-cache-service.aspx) The Distributed Cache service provides caching functionality to features (not to be confused with site features) in SharePoint Server 2013. The Distributed Cache service is either required by or improves performance of the following features:

   - Authentication
   - Newsfeeds
   - OneNote client access
   - Security Trimming
   - Page load performance
2. [Request Management Service](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16177.request-management-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx): Request Management feature in SharePoint 2013 manages incoming requests by evaluating logic rules against the user requests in order to determine what/which action to take, and which machine or machines (Targets) in the farm should handle the requests
3. [Shredd storage:](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2012/11/12/introduction-to-shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013-rtm-update/) Shredded Storage is both improves I/O and reduces compute utilization when making incremental changes to document or storing documents in SharePoint 2013.
4. User Interface: like Client side rendering, Optimized markup,Minimal Download,Image rendition,Device Channel, Content by Search.

Lastly, for SharePoint 2013 we will have better hardware which will also help to improve the performance.

Check this slide deck: [SharePoint 2013 Performance Enhancements](http://www.slideshare.net/eshupps/sharepoint-2013-performance-enhancements-18237589)

Comment: Also, javascript processing is much better in IE11 (SP 2013) vs IE9 (SP 2010)